# How would you sort csv rows by day?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a large csv file generated by a testing instrument in the field. The csv contains, among others, test IDs, signal response and dates. For example:

```
testID,date,signal
A123,2022/05/31 15:38:41,10
A234,2022/05/31 15:38:41,10
A123,2022/05/31 15:42:46,9
B123,2022/06/01 11:54:25,3
B234,2022/06/01 11:54:25,4
A123,2022/06/01 15:42:46,9
```

A test repeat is defined as more than one identical test ID occurring on the same day, and I need to remove these repeats from my dataset. I would need the most recent entry, discarding earlier entries.

Two identical test ID's occurring a month apart would both be considered valid, however.

My plan is to group each row by day, then check if the test IDs match, but I can't quite figure out a way to group rows by day.

**EDIT:** Ari Cooper-Davis provided a great tool for removing duplicate entries in the pandas library, solving half of my problem.

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['test_id'], keep='last')
```

However an issue in my case is that data points outside of each day are removed - two identical test ID's occurring a month apart would both be valid results. This is an odd quirk of the dataset I am working with at the moment.

The best solution is to run the above code snippet on each days results, rather than the whole dataset, which may risk removing valid data points.

Comment: Rolled back title edit - my main goal is to group csv entries by day (ie creation date), not to 'de-duplicate' entries, as the repeat signals may not necessarily be the same, just the test ID's, so I feel like this edit is inaccurate.

Comment: I think the title change was accurate - you are trying to deduplicate your dataframe, not sort it. You're trying to do that by grouping it by column values (which isn't necessary, see my answer), but you're still deduplicating!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).

For example (from the documentation linked above):

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...     'brand': ['Yum Yum', 'Yum Yum', 'Indomie', 'Indomie', 'Indomie'],
...     'style': ['cup', 'cup', 'cup', 'pack', 'pack'],
...     'rating': [4, 4, 3.5, 15, 5]
... })

>>> df
    brand style  rating
0  Yum Yum   cup     4.0
1  Yum Yum   cup     4.0
2  Indomie   cup     3.5
3  Indomie  pack    15.0
4  Indomie  pack     5.0

>>> df.drop_duplicates(subset=['brand'])
    brand style  rating
0  Yum Yum   cup     4.0
2  Indomie   cup     3.5
```

**Edit**: You can have more than one column in the `subset` argument. So for your sample data:

```
>>> df.drop_duplicates(subset=['date','testID'], keep='last')
  testID        date  signal
1   A234  2022-05-31      10
2   A123  2022-05-31       9
3   B123  2022-06-01       3
4   B234  2022-06-01       4
5   A123  2022-06-01       9
```

Note that I've had to convert your date column to just a date using:

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date
```

Comment: Adding the `keep='last'` flag is helpful - running this on the whole dataset could remove valid entries however. I really need to run this function on each day.

Comment: I've edited my answer to more clearly illustrate how the `subset` argument can be used to eliminate duplicates based on multiple columns.